# How to avoid parsing /etc/* files

Tags: zsh

When starting my shell with e.g. `exec zsh` from the command line, how can I have it **not** parse any /etc/ files?

I [read in the zsh guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html) that when a user starts a zsh shell, it processes the following init files in order:

```
# Every shell. Always
/etc/zshenv

# Every shell. Avoidable if passing flag -f to zsh
~/zshenv

# If it's a login shell.
/etc/zprofile
~/zprofile

# If it is an interactive shell
/etc/zshrc
~/zshrc

# If it is a login shell
/etc/zlogin
~/zlogin
```

When starting `zsh`, I would like to skip processing all the `/etc/*` files (except `/etc/zshenv` which I assume I can't skip as a non-root user?), and **only** parse my own init files in my home directory.

How can I do this when I invoke `exec zsh` from the command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unset the `GLOBAL_RCS` option. To do this, add `unsetopt GLOBAL_RCS` to `/etc/zshenv` or `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv` or run `zsh -o NO_GLOBAL_RCS`. Note that if `$ZDOTDIR` is unset, `$HOME` is used instead.

When `GLOBAL_RCS` is unset, `/etc/zprofile`, `/etc/zshrc`, `/etc/zlogin` and `/etc/zlogout` will not be sourced.

Comment: Thanks. I do not have admin rights to edit `/etc/zshenv`. I guess I can add this to `~/zshenv` instead?

Comment: That will work. You personal `zshenv` file is sourced right after `/etc/zshenv`, before the other config files are sourced. I have edited my answer to include that.